# createrepo and yum update with new rpm files, metadata?

Tags: yum

So I [almost] know how to update an offline rhel/centos 7 system, I am using a second identical system which is registered with RHN and other repositories.

In `/etc/yum.conf` I have `keep_cache = 1` and I have 1000+ rpms under `/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7Server/<repo>/packages/`

update: forgot to mention i also am doing `/etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo` having `file:///root/localrepo`

On the **first time**, if I put simply put ALL rpm's under one folder `/root/localrepo/` for example then do `createrepo /root/localrepo` then a `yum update` works fine.

In the future, on my RHN connected system I get new rpm's, I move and add them to my offline system under that `/root/localrepo` but a `yum update` does not automatically see them.  What is the correct usage of *createrepo* then to make `yum update` work as expected on this offline system?

Answer (score 0):

You need not only execute `createrepo`, but also install and run a web server, point it to the directory where the packages (repo) are located and add a record/file in the `/etc/yum-repos.d` directory, which points to your web server and path of your repo.

You may also skip the web server step, but in this case, your repo file should point to `file://path` instead of `http://server/path`.

Check out [this article](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-setting_repository_options) for more information about repo config files.

Here is example config file from the site above

```
[red-hat-enterprise-linux-scalable-file-system-for-rhel-6-entitlement-rpms]
name = Red Hat Enterprise Linux Scalable File System (for RHEL 6 Entitlement) (RPMs)
baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/entitlement-6/releases/$releasever/$basearch/scalablefilesystem/os
enabled = 1
gpgcheck = 1
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
sslverify = 1
sslcacert = /etc/rhsm/ca/redhat-uep.pem
sslclientkey = /etc/pki/entitlement/key.pem
sslclientcert = /etc/pki/entitlement/11300387955690106.pem
```

Comment: what do you mean by *exec createrepo* ?

Comment: I am familiar with your link of *8.4.2. Setting [repository] Options*... at least i think i am.   Hoping to simply drop new rpm files under my `/root/localrepo` and have `yum update` see them.  So far I've been deleting `/root/localrepo/repomond` then doing `createrepo /root/localrepo` again... seems like there should be a better way?

Comment: @ron, as I mention you should create repo file in `/etc/yum-repos.d` to "inform" `yum` you have new/other repo which the program can use

Comment: right, i have already done that (forget to mention) with `/etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo` having `baseurl=file:///root/localrepo`

Comment: @ron, did you enable this new repo? `yum-config-manager --enable repository...`

Comment: did not specifically do `yum-config-manager --enable` at the prompt, but my `/etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo` has `enabled=1` in it; and `yum update` works fine... the first time.

Comment: do i just need to maybe do a `createrepo --update /root/localrepo`   after I drop in new rpm files?

Comment: @ron, correct. For every change (in repo files) you must update with above command.